# How to plot a graph of training time and batch size of neural network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, plot, lstm

I'm currently working on a classification model built-up using TensorFlow framework applied with word embedding, LSTM layer, and Dense layer.

I wanted to see the performance of the training process; how much time Epoch took. So, instead of the boring figure(1), I want to plot a graph to show the training time and batch size like the figure(2). Does anyone know to archive that? I've been searching everywhere but none seems to work for me.

### Figure(1)

[image]

### Figure(2)

[image]

Comment: Already answered in multiple ways:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746507/keras-tensorflow-realtime-training-chart

Comment: history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=5 ,validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[custom_callback_5])

    
    plt.plot(epoch_1_time, epoch_5_time) *
    plt.plot(epoch_1_time, epoch_10_time)
    plt.plot(epoch_1_time, epoch_50_time)
    plt.plot(epoch_1_time, epoch_100_time)
    plt.legend(["epoch_5_time", "epoch_10_time", "epoch_50_time", "epoch_100_time"])
    plt.show()
    plt.close()